# How to create a help-form in FormsBuilder?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I am required to make a form which will contain important keywords and their description, with the possibility to search between the words. It is loaded from the `Help` menu and it is designed to give the users detailed help informations about other components. (Just like every application's Help menu)

I only used forms to query tables, and I was wondering, what is the correct way to achieve this? Does Oracle support any feature that would auto-generate a help-form based on my 'Help' inputs from Property Palettes? or do I have to manually write data into a canvas? if so, how can I search through it?

I considered creating a table and writing help informations in it, but I don't think that is the correct way.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're after, but if your form simply needs to retrieve a description given a keyword, then it makes sense to store them in a table and retrieve them using the form.

Comment: To answer your first question, no - Oracle doesn't provide any auto-generated help-form feature.

Comment: I would solve this with a table, e.g. `HELP_TOPICS (keyword, help_text)`, add a list item that contains all the keywords; when a user selects a keyword, query the table to find the help text, and set the value on a display-only text area item on the page.

Comment: I was expecting it could take all the "Help" tips from property palettes throughout the project, but good enough, you should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle Forms, unfortunately, does not give you programmatic access to values stored in property palettes, so your solution will need to be custom made.

Create a table, e.g. `HELP_TOPICS (keyword, help_text)`, add a list item that contains all the keywords; when a user selects a keyword, query the table to find the help text, and set the value on a display-only text area item on the page.